# How do I trigger my bot to DM a user after an on_message event discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot message a user directly if they type a certain word, for example the letter 'E', but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you mean:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   if(message.content == 'E'):
      await message.author.send('You typed E!')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this but for some reason nothing happens. I don't get an error but no message is sent, any idea why this could be?

Comment: @Matt What exactly did you type in discord?

Comment: @Matt is your bot running? Add a print message to the on_message event and first check if the event triggers, then try to send messages. Please note that 'typing' E alone doesn't trigger the event, you have to send a message containing only 'E' to trigger the answer.

Comment: BTW, This code is also case sensitive. So, you'd have to put uppercase `E`

Answer (score 1):

**Here few points to note that :**
`message.channel.send(<message>)` function is used for public responses like on sever.
`message.author.send(<message>)` function is used for private responses or for direct message(DM).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   if(message.content == 'E'):
      await message.author.send('You typed E!')`enter code here`
```

Comment: User want to `Direct Message (DM)` to `messaging author` not to public message, please try to change `message.channel` to `message.author`. But after that you answer will same as [FlameDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67213237/14867730) answer please try to update it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Member.create_dm()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.create_dm)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "e":
        dmchannel = await message.author.create_dm()
        await dmchannel.send("You typed E!")
```

Comment: For anyone copy-pasting this directly, there's a typo. it should say "if message.content.lower()"